# Source Port NAT with VPN

Tags: vpn, nat

I understand that a router (like an home router) does source port NAT (as the public IP for a LAN is normally one). If I run a VPN Client (like Open VPN) on a computer in the LAN and if the VPN packet is all encrypted (except for the external IP headers) how can the router:

1. add TCP segments to the packet in order to inject port NAT?
2. access the original TCP ports in order to understand the destination port?

Comment: there are lots of types of things people call VPN, and those technologies are implemented at different layers of the OSI model. L2TP based VPNs encrypt the layer2 payload, IPSec VPNs encrypt the layer3 payload, TLS/SSL VPNs like OpenVPN encrypt the layer Layer5 payload (session layer), etc.

Comment: Technically, OpenVPN encrypts at layer 2 (TAP) or 3 (TUN). How tunnel traffic is transported (UDP, TCP, GRE, whatever) is entirely unrelated to the “abstraction level” inside the tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand. TCP cannot be encrypted, otherwise it wouldn't be TCP anymore. So the router has access to the port field in the packet and can replace it as needed.

Of course, *inside* the packet may be yet another encrypted TCP packet. The router cannot access that and it doesn't need to. It is only concerned with the tunnel connection itself.

Comment: thanks. So that's the point indeed. Is there a TCP/IP packet (the one which needs to be encrypted) inside another TCP/IP packet (clear text one)?

Comment: Yes, that's how tunnels work. With fragmentation, there may not always be a complete packet inside though. Or it could be UDP, or any IP protocol. Or not even IP!

Answer (score 0):

> If I run a VPN Client (like Open VPN) on a computer in the LAN and if
> the VPN packet is all encrypted (except for the external IP headers)
> how can the router ..... ?

Any VPN Client I use in a remote location connecting to a VPN server and will handle NAT and connections automatically.

Be aware of any VPN setup needing to deal with NAT Traversal if the remote client is behind a double NAT (Cell Phone connection).

This is not necessarily automatic and some VPN clients cannot even handle this.

Top grade IPsec Clients (NCP) can do NAT Traversal automatically.

There is not One Size fits all, so examine your own situation.

I have used NCP for many years because of its unfailing flexibility.

Comment: ok thanks. But can you please be more specific on describing the technical process (as per my questions)?

Comment: You need to look at the Server setup and then consider how the client App interacts with it. I cannot be more specific than that.